# PHP cUrl adds random char, removes last one

Tags: php, curl, formatting, response

We have 4 servers running the same API. When I'm trying to call the same service on every server with PHP (5.4.12) cUrl (7.29.0), only one of them in particular gives me the expected response, no matter the time it's called :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><response><temporaryToken><token>1EDBABA96F1E98E2165571AAF5239808</token></temporaryToken></response>
```

The three other have some weird behaviour; the response returned gets a random character at the beginning, and sees its last character removed :

```
ã<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><response><temporaryToken><token>B319990DE262D75DD3E6B455741BB1C7</token></temporaryToken></response
```

This first character may be anything (latin alphanum, region specific, or invisible ones) and is never the same on each call. It seems that only this particular service has this behaviour, as the other ones all return a readable response.

The cUrl options are the following :

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->aHeader);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->iTimeoutRequest);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->iTimeoutRequest);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Am I triggering this weirdness, or is there a difference between our servers that we may have missed ?

Comment: Are you sending any mentionable headers in the request? The contents of `$this->aHeader` may be of interest.

Comment: Nothing funky I'm afraid, it only contains 'Content-type:application/xml' and a custom header, in the form of 'authToken:fvtjhw41jqxw2s8jiz2d5e7f5'.